# how can get date from string ? my code is enclosed here by

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];

NSDate *date1 =[[NSDate alloc] init];
date1 = [dateFormat dateFromString:@"11-nov-2013"];
NSLog(@"date is %@",date1); // it returns null
self.datePicker.date = date1;
[dateFormat release];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MMM-yyyy"];
NSDate *myDate = [formatter dateFromString:@"11-nov-2013"];
NSLog(@"date is %@",myDate);
```

Comment: @Ilesh he need to get date not the string.

Answer (score 0):

Set date format to

```
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the date format as well :

```
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
```